# SwiftUI onChange(of: ...) to update StateObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I built a custom `AsyncImage` view where the `ImageLoader` class fetches the image and updates the view when the image is retrieved. Since a `@StateObject` is initialized only the first time a view is built, I need a way for ImageLoader to fetch a new image if the url provided from a parent changes, which I do at the bottom with `onChange(of: url)...`. Is this ok to do or is there a better mechanism to update a `@StateObjects` parameters if a passed parent parameter changes?

```
struct URLImage: View, Equatable {  
  @StateObject private var loader = ImageLoader()
  private var url: URL?
  private var placeholder: UIImage?
  
  
  init(url: URL?, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.url = url
    self.placeholder = placeholder
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: loader.image ?? UIImage())
      .resizable()
      .opacity(loader.isLoading ? 0 : 1)
      .zIndex(5)
      .overlay(
        VStack {
          if loader.isLoading {
            ProgressView()
              .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
          }
        }
      )
      .background(
        VStack {
          if placeholder != nil && loader.isLoading == false && loader.image == nil {
            GeometryReader { geo in
              VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: placeholder!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .frame(width: geo.size.width / 3)
                  .foregroundColor(Theme.Colors.primary400)
              }
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
          }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Theme.Colors.primary200)
      )
      .onAppear {
        loader.url = url
      }
      .onChange(of: url) { newValue in
        if loader.url != newValue {
          loader.url = newValue
        }
      }
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    lhs.url == rhs.url
  }
}
```

Comment: Even with a Binding I would have to define a custom `Binding` that has a `set` that updates the `@StateObject` on a change. Why would that have any benefits over the way that I have it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the incoming URL as a `Binding`. Then, it will change, and will subsequently update the view body. When the view body is recomputed, the `onChange(of:perform:)` will be triggered, and so you can do whatever with the new `url`, `newValue`.

```
struct URLImage: View, Equatable {  
  @StateObject private var loader = ImageLoader()
  @Binding private var url: URL?
  private var placeholder: UIImage?
  
  
  init(url: Binding<URL?>, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
    _url = url
    self.placeholder = placeholder
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: loader.image ?? UIImage())
      .resizable()
      .opacity(loader.isLoading ? 0 : 1)
      .zIndex(5)
      .overlay(
        VStack {
          if loader.isLoading {
            ProgressView()
              .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
          }
        }
      )
      .background(
        VStack {
          if placeholder != nil && loader.isLoading == false && loader.image == nil {
            GeometryReader { geo in
              VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: placeholder!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .frame(width: geo.size.width / 3)
                  .foregroundColor(Theme.Colors.primary400)
              }
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
          }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Theme.Colors.primary200)
      )
      .onAppear {
        loader.url = url
      }
      .onChange(of: url) { newValue in
        if loader.url != newValue {
          loader.url = newValue
        }
      }
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    lhs.url == rhs.url
  }
}
```

Another method is to pass the `url` into the `ImageLoader`, if you create an init which accepts a `Binding<URL?>`. I think this is the better way because it's simpler, and less duplicated code. It means you can also cut out all the `onAppear` and `onChange` stuff:

```
struct URLImage: View, Equatable {  
  @StateObject private var loader: ImageLoader
  private var placeholder: UIImage?
  
  
  init(url: Binding<URL?>, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
    _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: ImageLoader(url: url))
    self.placeholder = placeholder
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: loader.image ?? UIImage())
      .resizable()
      .opacity(loader.isLoading ? 0 : 1)
      .zIndex(5)
      .overlay(
        VStack {
          if loader.isLoading {
            ProgressView()
              .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
          }
        }
      )
      .background(
        VStack {
          if placeholder != nil && loader.isLoading == false && loader.image == nil {
            GeometryReader { geo in
              VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: placeholder!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .frame(width: geo.size.width / 3)
                  .foregroundColor(Theme.Colors.primary400)
              }
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
          }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Theme.Colors.primary200)
      )
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    lhs.loader.url == rhs.loader.url
  }
}
```

Side note: I don't recommend you use this `Equatable` implementation here. This will cause many problems in the future when you add other variables and objects - you just don't need it. SwiftUI implicitly calculates if a view is equatable by checking everything which is `Equatable`, is equatable. I recommend you just remove the conformance on this view.

Comment: The issue I have with using a Binding is that its not always convenient to create a `@State` object. For instance, if I have a `Person` model and that person model has a property for image e.g. `let image: URL`, if I were to create a view from this model, I would need to create a `@State` variable in the view and assign the image property to the `@State` object, whereas with my method you can pass the property directly to the view. And agreed with the Equatable. It was just me trying to solve another issue and messing around :)

Comment: @Darkisa If you have an `ObservableObject`, you can directly access the binding of a property with `$objectName.propertyName`. So you say you got a `Person` model, so you would do something like `$person.image` which would be of type `Binding<URL>`.